# Fingerprint Login USB reader

Tags: login-screen, 20.10, fingerprint-reader

I recently received a BENSS usb fingerprint reader and I would like to use it with my ubuntu 20.10

lsusb returns the following :

[image]

On fprintd-enroll I receive No device available :

[image]

Result for `sudo dmesg | grep Goodix` is :
[image]

Any idea ?

Found some drivers at this address :

http://www.benss-tech.com/index.php/download-c8.html

Any idea how to install the .dll ?

Comment: Does it not need you to install a driver?

Comment: As it is recognized in lsusb, I was thinking not, but I found some drivers to download on the manufacturer site, they are.dll do you know how to install them ?

Comment: .dll is for windows do they not have drivers for Ubuntu?

Comment: Sorry, I think they are installer as I get a result when sudo dmesg | grep Goodix, as drivers I have a .cat and a .inf also ?